# Prevent FetchContent from being re-configured if already configured

Tags: cmake, fetchcontent

I have several `FetchContent`s Github repos in my `CMakeLists.txt` and they get reconfigured by CMake every time I modify my `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
FetchContent_Declare(fmt GIT_REPOSITORY https://github.com/fmtlib/fmt)
FetchContent_MakeAvailable(fmt)

FetchContent_Declare(glfw GIT_REPOSITORY https://github.com/glfw/glfw) 
FetchContent_MakeAvailable(glfw)

# Several more GitHub repositories using FetchContent
# ...
```

Is it possible to set `FetchContent` to skip the library that is already `FetchContent`ed?

Comment: No, you cannot tell CMake to not reconfigure a project added via `FetchContent` when the main project is modified. `FetchContent_MakeAvailable` is effectively `add_subdirectory` call, so `FetchContent`-ed project becomes **part of the main** project. If you want to build external project once, then use `ExternalProject_Add`.

Comment: Makes perfect sense. Thank you.